# Quotient of unitary group by special unitary group

Tags: group-theory

Can someone help me, I don't understand the following question.

"Using without proof, the homomorphism theorem, or otherwise, show that
$U(n)/SU(n)$ is isomorphic to  $U(1)$."

Here, $U(n)$ is the [unitary group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group) while $SU(n)$ is the [special unitary group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group).

Comment: What part don't you understand - do you need help with the definitions of $\mathrm{U}(n)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(n)$?

Comment: Yes, there is no question here.

Comment: @ZevChonoles no I have those definitions, could you help me show that its isomorphic to U(1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the determinant map $\det:\mathrm{U}(n)\to \mathrm{U}(1)$, the kernel of which is (by definition) $\mathrm{SU}(n).$ Apply the first homomorphism theorem.

Comment: Thanks, mind if I send this to someone else?

Comment: No, that would be fine.